# Assembly Debugger

Tags: gratis, linux, programming, debugging, assembly

I'm writing code in (amd64/x86_64) assembly that needs debugging, and I'm trying to find a good tool for it. I'm currently using [nemiver](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nemiver), but it's more C-centric than I prefer; while I can get it to assembly mode, it's annoying to use.

I'm on a GNU/Linux system.

Comment: How much may this Debugger cost ? X64dbg and windbg are no options ?

Comment: I'd prefer if it were free/open source

Comment: [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)? Should be the WinDbg equivalent for Linux. https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html

Comment: nemiver's basically a GUI for gdb, but I'd like something with e.g. a stack display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Evan's Debugger. (open source for linux) 
https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger 
http://www.codef00.com/projects#debugger

Printscreen:
[image: Evan's Debugger]

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, but I'm still getting a mysterious segfault at a movabs from register to stack. Ah well. I'll leave this open for another day so anyone else who wants to can answer, then I'll accept unless there's a magic find-your-segfault tool in someone else's answer.